# Grouping Over Specific Combinations of Variables With data.table

Tags: r, data.table

My question is a follow-up to [Grouping Over All Possible Combinations of Several Variables With dplyr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28992028/grouping-over-all-possible-combinations-of-several-variables-with-dplyr). In above thread, the poster was looking at grouping by all combinations of grouping variables using `dplyr.` However, this solution doesn't work for my dataset because of memory and size limitations. Can someone please help me with `data.table` version of it?

Input data and output format are going to be the same as that of the question in above post and Gregor's answer. So, for sake of brevity, I am not posting it again.

I tried this myself using `data.table`, but I don't know how to nest `data.table` operations inside `do.call().` I searched for this, and found [do.call to build and execute data.table commands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13869144/do-call-to-build-and-execute-data-table-commands), but Matt's post is beyond my comprehension.

I'd appreciate any help.